# ExtJS Grid Selection

Tags: css, extjs, grid

I am new to extjs 4. In my requirement the users selects a cell in a grid, that cell alone need to highlight. Instead of that the whole row has been highlighted. how to fix this issue?

Comment: refer [cell selection](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.selection.CellModel)

Comment: it is not useful. This is what i need [(http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?144094-Grid-highlight-selected-cell-with-RowSelectionModel)]

Comment: Maybe edit the question and explain exactly what you need?

Answer (score 0):

you have to edit css (of row and cell class when hover event occure) based on selecting cell not row selecting.